# Want to display Transparent TextView

Tags: android-layout, textview

I want to add the transparent `Textview` of Contact us on as shown in [the picture](http://img.informer.com/screenshots_siandroid/1795/1795355_1_2.jpg) below, Also I want to add the golden colored horizontal line of the same image. Please help me how can I add these things, I am new to android.

Comment: if you want to transparent view then set background transparent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want the background of your `TextView` to be transparent, you have to define it's background color as `#00000000.`
First two are it's alpha state that is the transparency, which you can adjust accordingly. It ranges from 00-FF and rest 6 are RGB values.

For the line:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#CFB53B"/>
```

You can set the color of the line through `android:background`, width through `android:layout_width` and thickness through `android:layout_height`.

Comment: Can you please check that link of image I want to exactly as in d image, I want transparent but background color is of Black.

Comment: YA...so adjust the opacity #00000000 .Here last 6 zeros represent hex code of black and first two zeros represent opacity.... it ranges from 00-FF.try adjusting it...it will work for sure.If you want it to be opaque then make it ff and if complete transparent then 00 and if you want it to be in between(translucent) then adjust it accordingly.

Comment: hey Thanks it works.. but havent tried that transparent background thing, will let u know thanks.